# Redundancy vs. Flexibility

Tags: mysql, database

I am new to MySQL database and I'm collaborating with my former CSCI teacher to make a student database that holds his student grades history. My original idea was to have a Students table (studentID, firstname, lastname, middlename, gender), a Course table (courseID, course_description), a Grades table (studentID, courseID, year, final_grade), and then tables for AssignmentScores, TestScores, QuizScores, and ExerciseScores. Each of these tables would of course have a studentID, courseID, year, and section (code used by the school to define the semester and period) field, along with the scores earned by the students.

The problem with this approach is that in a perfect world, all courses would have the same number of assignments, exercises, tests, and quizes, and they all would have the same point value, however, as we all know, this is not a perfect world. For instance, there are a couple of courses that have assignments labeled 1a, and 1b both worth five points each as opposed to the normal 10 points each for 10 assignments (labeled 1 through 10). This is also the first year he started keeping track of exercises, and all classes do not have the same number of exercises, nor are they always worth the same point value.

In order to allow for flexibility, we decided to make a table containing general course information with a courseID, year, section, type (to designate quiz, assignment, test, or exercise), number (1a, 1b, or 1,2,3 etc...), and a maxpoints field (to hold the max point value per item). We would then also have a table for individual scores which would have basically the same fields but instead of max points there would an earnedpoints field (to hold the students scores on a particular item). He would then of course have to enter every courses details, every year, regardless of if it was different then the previous year's.

For the two courses he is currently teaching, that amounts to 90 rows per table with much of the data seemingly redundant.

Doing it this way seems to have a lot of redundant information, but I don't see any other way that allows for past, present, or future flexibility. One of the reasons I am doing this project is in hopes of using it to show prospective employers and I thought the point of a relational database was to minimize redundant information, and I don't want prospective employers to look at this and say, "what an idiot."

So my question to the stackoverflow community is, "is there a better way to do this?"

Comment: You could provide a tool to copy details from one year to the next, then the instructor can edit the new year to make any necessary modifications.

Comment: It would help to see an ERD to formulate an answer.  Note that a normalized relational database aims to store every fact only once, it doesn't matter if values are duplicated.